# Deploying .net addin application

Tags: installation, setup-deployment, visual-studio-addins

I have developed my first .net addin.

Now comes the part to deploy it and im lost.

In the .NET Setup and Deployment project, i have configured the Application folder to

contain all the dlls and the add-in file itself.

Now comes the requirement to automate the Add-in deployment in the VS2008 editor.

1. Is there a way, where on successful installation,the addin is automatically added in   the Addin manager (i.e after folder is configured in the Add-in / Macros security automatically ? )
2. Pop up the Usage document file which is included as a file in the Application folder  on successfull installation.